# Является ли изменение состояния объекта проблемой?

Tags: java, объекты

В следующем коде нарушается принцип инкапсуляции, потому что метод `getHireDay()` возвращает объект `Date`. Изменить его где-то в ином классе, вызвавшем метод `getHireDay()`, значит изменить состояние объекта `Employee`.

```
class Employee 
{ 
    private Date hireDay; 

    public Date getHireDay(); 
    { 
        return hireDay; 
    }
}
```

В следующем коде вроде как проблема снимается. Изменить состояние объекта `Employee` где-то в другом классе, вызвавшем метод `getHireDay()`, не удастся.

```
class Employee 
{ 
    private Date hireDay; 

    public Date getHireDay(); 
    { 
        return hireDay.clone(); 
    }
}
```

Вопрос. Является ли изменение состояния объекта проблемой, ведь объектов данного класса может быть сколько угодно? В каких случаях необходимо заботиться о состоянии объекта, точнее о неизменяемости его состояния?

Comment: При вызове метода getHireDay() состояние объекта не меняется вообще. Меняется, к примеру, сеттером

Comment: По-моему, это зависит от конкретной ситуации. Если важно не давать возможность изменять содержимое поля, а также что копирование объекта не является проблемой в плане производительности, то можно возвращать копию. В каких-то ситуациях вообще вместо самого объекта можно возвращать конкретное значение из него, не подвергая "угрозе" сам объект.

Comment: Зато у возвращённого `Date` можно изменить состояние (например, с помощью метода `setTime`), что таки изменит состояние `Employee`, ибо у него поменяет дата найма.

Comment: Описанная проблема называется unsafe publication. В одних ситуациях она несущественна. В других - опасна.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Объекты всегда можно условно разделить на два типа:

1. мутабельные (изменяемые)
2. немутабельные(неизменяемые)

Что такое мутабельные объекты: это объекты, которые имеют состояние и имеют методы для изменения этого состояния. Т.е. привычные для нас Plain Old Java Objects с геттерами и сеттерами.

Немутабельные - это такие объекты, которые после их создания(вызова конструктора) не могут меняться.

Каждый из этих типов имеет свои преимущества и недостатки.

Преимущества немутабельности:

1. Неизменяемые объекты - это хорошие ключи в Map и Set, поскольку они
   обычно не изменяются после создания.
2. Немутабельность упрощает запись, использование и понимание кода (инвариант класса устанавливается один раз и затем неизменен)
3. Неизменяемость упрощает параллелизацию вашей программы, поскольку конфликты между объектами отсутствуют.
4. Внутреннее состояние вашей программы будет консистентным, даже если у вас возникли исключения.
5. Ссылки на неизменные объекты могут кэшироваться, поскольку они не будут изменяться.
6. Неизменяемые объекты являются потокобезопасными, поэтому у вас не будет проблем с синхронизацией.

Но за эти преимущества надо платить, поэтому придется тратить время на создание новых объектов, каждый раз, когда хотим изменить состояние, придется так же подумать о том, какой объект можно назвать немутабельным, потому что ваш объект к сожалению мутабельный. Т.е. нужно держать в голове правила для создания немутабельных объектов, а именно

1. Сделать все поля приватными
2. Не предоставлять геттеры/сеттеры и другие мутаторы
3. Убедитесь, что методы нельзя переопределить, создав финальный класс (Strong Immutability) или сделав свои методы финальным (Weak Immutability)
4. Если поле не является примитивным или немутабельным(как например Date), то сделайте полное клонирование этого объекта.

В общем, ответ на ваш вопрос: мутабельность сама по себе проблемой не является! Она активно используется в разработке, когда предметная область представлена анемичной моделью данных (только геттеры/сеттеры и в объектах нет методов поведения) и все с этим отлично живут. Но если вы хотите назвать объект иммутабельным, использовать его в качестве ключа в мапе использовать его в многопоточном окружении, то позаботьтесь о пунктах указанных выше.

Comment: Поправка: неизменяемые объекты называют *иммутабельными*